# how do convert value of "range" to float numbers in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, range

When I add float numbers in value="3.4567890", it converts to number type 'int'. I don't want it convert to number type 'int'. I want it to be 'number' or type 'float'.

Example:

```js
const rangeValue = document.querySelector('input');
console.log(rangeValue.value);
```

```html
<input type="range" min="0" max="0" value="3.4567890">
```

`console.log` converts to number type int.

Comment: An input's `value` attribute is never type 'int', as there is no integer type in JavaScript. It is also not type 'number'. Input value is always type 'string'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `max` attribute should be above the `value` for the value to be retrieved properly. (Right now, your `min` is the same as your `max`, at 0)

Set a `step` attribute to a very low amount, like 0.0000001:

```js
const rangeValue = document.querySelector('input');
console.log(rangeValue.value);
```

```html
<input type="range" min="0" max="10" step="0.0000001" value="3.4567890">
```

Comment: This technically answers the question but I have yet to see an application where 0.0000001 is the desired step value.